# Braced block of statement is an unused closure in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewDidAppear(animated)

if let directoryURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0] as? NSURL {

    let urls = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(directoryURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions.SkipsHiddenFiles)
    //Error: Errors thrown from here are not handled

    catch let error as NSError {
    //Error: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
    //Error: Braced block of statements is an unused closure
    //Error: Expected expression

        print("There's an error")
    }

    downloadedPhotoURLs = urls as [NSURL]
    collectionView!.reloadData()
}
}
```

This error is pretty wierd, there seems nothing wrong with the try/catch pattern since it works fine on my other projects, but I don't know why Xcode doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use `do`:

```
if let directoryURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0] as? NSURL {
    do {
        let urls = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(directoryURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions.SkipsHiddenFiles)
        downloadedPhotoURLs = urls as [NSURL]
        collectionView!.reloadData()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
}
```